# java How do you convert Date to Hours and Minutes

Tags: java, jodatime, formatter

How do you convert Date to Hours and Minutes?
a way like this:

```
Date d=new Date();
String str=convertToMyFormat(d);
print(str);
// for example for date Sat Jan 03 04:40:00 GMT+03:30 1970 print should be some 
//thing  like this:
>> str ="50:10";
```

if date create by this code:

```
Period p = new Period(0l);
p = p.plusDays(2);
p = p.plusMinutes(70);
d=new Date(p.toStandardDuration().getMillis());
```

this solution

```
public String convertToMyFormat(Date d){
 Duration du=new Duration(d.getTime())
 str=du.toStandardHours().getHours() + ":"+ du.getMinutes();
 return str;
}
```

print minutes greater than 60. "49:70"

i need way that if minutes greater than 60 increment hours.
every solution that convert java.util.date or long to this format is acceptable. if duration is greater than 24h should increment hours not add day

Comment: 1425 hours relative to what?  And, do you tag the question Jodatime because a solution based on Jodatime would be acceptable?

Comment: every solution that convert java.util.date or long to this format is acceptable. 1425 hours means for example a month is about 720 minutes, if date is greater than 24h should increment hours not add day.

Comment: _if date is greater then 24h_ makes no sense whatsoever. You realize that a date (e.g. June 25th, 2014) is not a duration, right?

Comment: I assume that you mean "a month is about 720 hours", not ***minutes***.  But then, where do you get that 1425 from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need the hours in the current month, and the minutes, using Jodatime:

```
public static String convert (DateTime input) {
    int hours = (input.getDayOfMonth() - 1) * 24 + input.getHourOfDay();
    return String.format("%d:%02d",hours,input.getMinuteOfHour());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert(new DateTime("2014-01-01T22:09")) );
    System.out.println(convert(new DateTime("2014-01-03T22:21")) );
    System.out.println(convert(new DateTime("2014-01-31T22:44")) );
}
```

outputs

```
22:09
70:21
742:44
```

EDIT: same principle for offset within the current year:

```
public static String convertOffsetInYear (DateTime input) {
    int hours = (input.getDayOfYear() - 1) * 24 + input.getHourOfDay();
    return String.format("%d:%02d",hours,input.getMinuteOfHour());
}
```

If you need more exotic reference times (that is, the moment from which the distance in hours needs to be calculated) you could check out Duration and PeriodFormatterBuilder.

Comment: The main problem is missing reference time in the signature of convert-method. The question is not clear at all about timestamp versus duration. We should not encourage the OP to use methods with such signatures. If the method had at least TWO args of type `DateTime` then it might be tolerated (suggesting a better method name like "between").

Comment: @MenoHochschild I tried **twice** in the comments to make OP explain the origin of 1425, to no avail.  Because I got no answer, I hoped that a first, admittedly naive approach - but already with a pointer to more sophisticated, generic and reusable solutions - might help OP to at last properly formulate the problem.  Not so, what do you want me to do about it?  Question is now on hold, which is totally justified I think for those oh so frequent cases where people despite assistance don't even manage to more or less clearly formulate the problem they're having.

Comment: @fvu Well, you have done your efforts ;-)

Comment: @AhmadReza Even after your edit the question itself is not clear. The main point is: A `Date` is not a duration but a point on global timeline, hence it is principially not convertible to a duration. You really need a SECOND `Date` instance as referencing time point. Which one?

Comment: @MenoHochschild  Why Date not convertible to a duration `Date date=new Date(); Duration dur=new Duration(date.getTime());` I should **Convert Date to hours and miniutes** which part of this question Is ambiguous?

Comment: @AhmadReza A `java.util.Date` is a POINT in time while a duration is a DISTANCE on the timeline. The mathematical difference is obvious.

Comment: @MenoHochschild but we can convert duration to date and vice versa. `Date` is type of `Duration`. now Date is  Duration from Thu Jan 01 03:30:00 GMT+03:30 1970 until now  `Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  Duration dur=new Duration(time.getTime());
  System.out.println(dur.getMillis());
  System.out.println(time.getTime());` **this code print same thing two time!**

Comment: @fvu i solved my problem with the solution you've suggested(with some modificatio). tanx

Comment: @AhmadReza Well, internally `Date` uses a special duration as state model, namely a duration between the fixed point 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and the (end) timestamp to be modelled. But this does not change the fact that the `Date`-object itself is no duration but a timestamp. It is not natural for me and most other people to use UNIX epoch as start of an interval and then to be silent about this completely arbitrary choice in the question itself.